# Time complexity of a generator expression in python

Tags: python, time-complexity

I was solving a problem where given two strings `s` and `t`, the aim is to find if `s` is a subsequence of `t`.
I came across a solution:

```
def isSubsequence(s, t):
   t = iter(t)
   return all(c in t for c in s)
```

I want to know what would be the time complexity of this solution.
Here's what I figured out:

First, we turned `t` into a iterator, and what that does is that `c in t` iterates through the iterator until the first position where it finds a match.
Second, `c in t for c in s` is a generator: it returns an iterator.
Third, `all()` takes in an iterator as an argument and loops through to find the first `False`. If it can't find it, it return `True`.

The for loop that iterates over `s` has O(s) complexity and let's say `c` is the last letter in `t` that's O(t) complexity. Also since this is different from a nested for loop so the complexity won't be O(s * t).
Can you help me in this context.

Comment: Complexity is O(s+t) since you only go through s and t once.

Comment: @DarrylG Can you please share some insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iterator can only be traversed once. For example,

```
>>> t = iter([1,2,3])
>>> list(t)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(t)
[]
>>> list(t)
[]
```

The function takes advantage of the fact that `c in t` will only consume as much of the iterator as necessary to determine if `c` if found. When `c` is found, iteration stops until the next time you evaluate `c in t`, at which point you pick up where you left off in `t`. Once you reach the end of `t`, all further calls to `c in t` will return immediately, because the iterator won't reset itself. Thus, `all(c in t for c in s)` will make `len(s)` calls to `c in t`, but the *accumulated* number of comparisons made over the course of those calls is just `len(t)`; you'll look at each element of the original `t` argument at most one time.

Comment: That explains why the time complexity will be O(s + t), I was overlooking the fact that the iteration will stop once a 'c' in 't' is found for a 'c' in 's'. Thanks for the answer.